# Passing dynamic variable to graphQL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby

I need to pass a dynamic variable to my graphQL Query. I am using a typescript. But i am getting error "expected two arguments but got one".

**My Query is:**

```
export const queryFragment = graphql`
  query fqlQuery1($slug: String!) {
    allFile {
      edges {
        node {
          childFaqsJson {
            title
            questions {
              title
              content
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    result: faqsJson(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      title
      questions {
        title
        content
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default graphql(queryFragment, {
  //*** --> Here i am getting error, not able to pass two arguments_***
  options: {
    variables: {
      slug: '/en/faqs/borrower-eligibility/',
    },
  },
})(Faq);
```

**in src/declarations.d.ts**

I have declared the constant like this

```
declare const graphql: (query: TemplateStringsArray) => void;
```

If I add the queryVariable like this
declare const graphql: (query: TemplateStringsArray, queryVariable?: any) => void;
then it give following error

> [ts] Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'TemplateStringsArray'. const queryFragment: void